# OpenGL - Apply transformation to polygon in 3D space

Tags: c++, opengl, transformation, glm-math

I am trying to rotate a quad in a 3D space. The following code shows the vertex shader utilized to draw the quad:

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 aColor;

out vec3 ourColor;

uniform mat4 transform;
uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = transform*(projection*view*model*vec4(aPos, 1.0f));
    ourColor = aColor;
}
```

The quad is displayed when `transform` is not multiplied to `projection*view*model*vec4(aPos,1.0f)` but is not displayed when it is multiplied as above.
The code for transformation:

```
trans=glm::rotate(trans,(float)(glfwGetTime()),glm::vec3(0.0,0.0,1.0));
float scaleAmount = sin(j*0.3);j=j+0.035;
trans=glm::scale(trans,glm::vec3(scaleAmount,scaleAmount,scaleAmount));
unsigned int transformLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "transform");
glUniformMatrix4fv(transformLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(trans));
glBindVertexArray(VAO);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

I have set the uniform present in the vertex shader as well.
Why is it not rotating and scaling, or even appearing when I multiply `transform` with `(projection*view*model*vec4(aPos,1.0f))` ? 

**Edit:** I figured out that the problem is with scaling, since the code works with rotation only. The code does not work with scaling only.

Comment: Try `gl_Position = projection * view * transform * model * vec4(aPos,1.0f)`

Comment: @Ripi2 did not work.

Comment: Do you understand "transformations"? If not, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/850239/3871028).

Comment: @Rabbid76 first comment. Also, I've found that the problem has something to do with scaling.

Comment: I've got it ! I initialized `j` variable as an integer. So, for the scale function, `j=j+0.035` was always 0. Hence, the quad didn't appear.I'm sorry for all the trouble and thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `scaleAmount == 0.0`:

```
glm::mat4 trans( 1.0f );
float scaleAmount = 0.0f;
trans=glm::scale(trans,glm::vec3(scaleAmount,scaleAmount,scaleAmount));
```

then this would cause that `trans` is

```
{{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}}
```

Since `sin(0.0) == 0.0` it has to be ensured that in case of `sin(j*0.3);`, `j` is not equal 0.0.

Comment: Yup, that was it. I had initialized j as an integer. So j+0.035, did not make a difference and j was still 0.

Answer (score 1):

Let's think only in 2D.

The quad is defined in "world" coordinates. To rotate it *around some point* move the quad to that point, then rotate and scale it and then move it back.

Doing this with matrices is the same as `transform * model`  where `transform` is something like

```
transform = moveback * scale * rotate * movetopoint
```

Comment: I tried it. I've noticed that the code works with rotation only and doesn't with scaling only. It has something to do with the scaling of the quad.