# How 3D projection works?

Tags: javascript, math, 3d

If there is a camera with a given fov and aspect ratio values at `(0, 0, 0)` looking straight down the Z axis, and there is a triangle `(x1, y1, z1), (x2, y2, z2), (x3, y3, z3)`, and the canvas is 1024*768 pixel, then how will it be calculated (in a right-handed coordinate system)? Are there any easy to understand example codes somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course there is simple. Here on Wikipedia is all information you need: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection

And if you need some code: http://codeincodeblock.blogspot.sk/2012/03/projecting-3d-world-co-ordinates-into.html

And here on stack is similar question: [3d to 2d Projection Matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130829/3d-to-2d-projection-matrix?rq=1)